# Marketing Cloud: Accessing _smsmessagetracking data view records using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, marketingcloudapi, data-views

I wonder if it is possible to retrieve records from the [_smsmessagetracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) data view using SOAP API. I have found [Sent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sentevent.htm), [Open](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/openevent.htm), [Click](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/clickevent.htm), [Bounce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/bounceevent.htm) and few other objects in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm) but I need an object for SMS Message Tracking.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

All information in relation to Contacts and Mobile Studio (which is what `_smsmessagetracking` is in relation to) is contained inside of REST API only. You should check out the official docs around SMS REST API endpoints and Contact endpoints **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm)** and that should direct you to the right API calls necessary to get the relevant information you are looking for.

If you need assistance in setting up and running the REST API, please check out my blog post **[here](https://gortonington.com/introduction-to-making-api-calls-to-sfmc-from-postman/)** for the basics on set up and a sample call via POSTman. Then you can check out samples of making REST API calls inside of SFMC **[here](https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/)**